# RxSwift double mapping in tableView.rx.itemSelected

Tags: ios, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I want to get object from `tableView.rx.itemSelected` and after process it. This method return `IndexPath`, so I can map this value. But how to get object at index from the `ViewModel`?

```
struct ViewModel {
    var items: Observable<[Item]>
}
```

Approximate I expect something like this (but this flow is wrong):

```
tableView.rx.itemSelected
        .map { indexPath -> Item in 
        return viewModel.items.map {$0[indexPath.row]}
        }
        ..subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] item in
        //other actions with Item object
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I showed somewhere this possibility, but cant recollect it. Have you some idea how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just return `viewModel.items[indexPath.row]` in `map` function?

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko In this case I get error: Type 'Observable<[Item]>' has no subscript members

Comment: What type of `viewModel.items`?

Comment: It is: var items: Observable<[Item]>

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you need both `indexPath` and the `model` you could combine the 2 methods and transform them in only one observable sequence:

```
Observable
    .zip(tableView.rx.itemSelected, tableView.rx.modelSelected(String.self))
    .bind { [unowned self] indexPath, model in
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("Selected " + model + " at \(indexPath)")
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: is not optimal solution, because https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926473/7104327 Here

Answer (score 10):

RxCocoa has 2 methods:

`public var itemSelected: ControlEvent<IndexPath> { get }` which returns `IndexPath` of selected item 
and 
`public func modelSelected<T>(_ modelType: T.Type) -> ControlEvent<T>` which returns the model element 
In accordance to your example it will look:

```
    tableView.rx.modelSelected(Item.self)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] item in
            // other actions with Item object
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right about 2nd flow. I have used it but I want to increase my understanding. Therefore itemSelected processing is asked.

Answer (score 2):

Also I have found other way add `do(onNext:{...})` after `itemSelected` command:

```
tableView.rx
    .itemSelected
    .do(onNext: { [unowned self] indexPath in
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    })
    .map { indexPath -> Item in 
        return viewModel.items.map {$0[indexPath.row]}
    }
    .subscribe(self.viewModel.reviewTimeAction.inputs)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```